# Javascript code to run every 10 minutes and close invoked windows once loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want a javascript that can open link in every 10 minutes and close the opened tab once the tab is completely loaded, I tried the following code and its working fine but the tab is getting closed instantly, want to close it once its completely loaded.

```
var mywindow;
setInterval(function() {
  mywindow = window.open("https://www.google.com");
  mywindow.close();
}, 2000);
```

Comment: What is the point of opening a window just to close it? `mywindow.addEventListener('load', function(){ this.close(); })`

Comment: @Shan Please only use Stack Snippets when the code is *runnable*. The iframe is sandboxed, it can't open windows.

Answer (score 0):

If the page is on a different domain, you won't be able to listen for the page to load unless you can run scripts on that other domain. The only way to do something like this on a page you don't own is for the user to have a browser extension that allows that functionality, such as Tampermonkey, and use the following userscript:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Close Google
// @match        https://www.google.com
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

// this will run automatically once the DOM is loaded
window.close();
```

But it's not very reasonable to ask every user of your script to do that - an alternative would be to simply wait some amount of time, a second or few, to make sure the page is loaded, then `.close()` it:

```
setInterval(function () {
    const newWindow = window.open("https://www.google.com");
    setTimeout(() => {
        newWindow.close();
    }, 3000);
}, 10 * 60_000);
```

If you want the link to be opened every 10 minutes, pass `10 * 60_000` to the outer `setTimeout`, not `2000`.

Comment: I'm getting this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: etInterval is not defined"

Comment: Sounds like you misspelled it. Just like in the code in my answer, it needs to be `setInterval`, not `etInterval`

Comment: Did you try the code in my question, fixing the typo?